# How to rewrite a Postgres function to return a scalar value and a table value (instead of a refcursor)?

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions, ref-cursor

I have a function that returns two `OUT` parameters: one is a scalar value and the other is a `refcursor`.

I don't want to use `refcursor` as `OUT` parameter, since it is not compatible with power builder. I need that function to return one scalar value and a table.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a function return both a scalar and a table. It is either/or.

You could return a table with an added column that is the scalar and is the same for all result rows. Or write two functions.